# Control Event Manager displays nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, events

i can't see anymore the control event list on VS19. It was working at the beginning of the project but i don't know when this issue occured.

When i create any control's event i can't see its event manager anymore as you can see on the following screeshot. If i delete the control's event, the manager will display again and this issue occure on every control i try(datagrid, buttons, textbox ..).
The events are still working.

> Screenshot https://i.ibb.co/syG7XMZ/Sans-titre.jpg

If i delete the event the tab displays again the eventlist.

XAML code :

```xml
<Window x:Class="ApPG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApPG"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ControlsGrid" Background="Black">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="tboxdebug" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="658,10,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="18"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxdebug" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="658,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="22" />
            <Button x:Name="Btn_debug" Content="FNC1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="678,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Btn_debug_Click" Height="20" Width="64"/>
            <Button x:Name="Btn_debug2" Content="FNC2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="663,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Btn_debug2_Click" Height="20" Width="47" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="pldatagrid" Margin="0,0,150,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" PreviewMouseDown="InventoryMouseDown" />
            <DataGrid x:Name="otherdatagrid" Margin="0,0,150,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" PreviewMouseDown="InventoryMouseDown" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know i can create my events manually but i wish to understand why i can't access anymore to this panel when i already created an event while i could do it on my others projects?

Thanks,

PS : sorry i can't add any image on this thread while i don't have 10 reputations

Comment: I tried to find out why this is happening but i can't. 
This issue is occuring only on this project and i couldn't reproduce it on any other project... If anyone experienced this situation please let me know

Comment: How about reloading the properties Window by pressing Ctrl+ s ? If it not work, reset layout[Window > Reset Window Layout] to check if it works. By the way, sometime the large usage of VS in the background leads to this issue too，you can close all the VS solutions and then open this project only to check if it ok.

Comment: Hello dead @DasiyTianMSFT, thanks for you answer. 
I tried to reload the window properties as you said but ctrl+s is saving the current window and nothing happens on the event properties window. Also, i tried to reset the window layout but it's still not working. The only one project opened is this project, nothing worked for me...
Thanks anyway mate i'll keep searching about this issue

Comment: I never found any way to solve this issue. So i made another project and pasted in it all my old project and this is good.
Thanks anyway to all those who tried to help me with this issue.